# Trying to get my Discord bot to respond with "Im not a boomer >:(" but it won't respond. How can I fix the code?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, discord.js

I made a Discord bot, and the bot will go online, but whenever I say boomer, the bot won't respond with Im not a boomer >:( like it's supposed to. What is wrong with my code? The marked out area in the picture is my token. The part of the code that says, "Enter token here", is where the token actually is. I took it out because I didn't want anyone getting the token. This is all in visual studio code.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');


const bot = new Discord.Client();



const token = 'Enter token here';


bot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('This bot is online!');
})

 if(msg.content ===  "boomer"){
        msg.reply('Im not a boomer!>:(');
    }
})

bot.login(token);
```

[New code image link...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQ1XV.png)

Comment: why show the code in the image that already is in the text

Comment: I thought it might be easier for people to know what the code is if I had it there two different ways. Do you know what my issue is? If so please tell me.

Comment: Is your bot on the same server, can it speak?

Comment: It is on the same server when I was trying to run the command, but it wouldn't speak. That is the issue that I'm dealing with. It wont answer back with the correct text. I say boomer and it is supposed to answer with Im not a boomer >:(, but it won't.  I suspect something is wrong with the code.

Comment: If they are unable to read the text version do you really think they will be able to read the image version? The text version can be scaled and improve the readability, this is not the case with the image. And you don't know how long the image will be online.

Answer (score 0):

This could be for a number of reasons. I'm going to assume that the image is a newer version of the code because your message handler is inside the on 'message' event in the picture but not in the code. If it's not, there's your problem.

1. The bot doesn't have permission to speak in the channel.
2. The message was not exactly `boomer`. You have `===` when checking for the message so it will only ever check if it's exactly the same.

If this is the case, you can get around this by using `toLowerCase()` and `includes()` like so:
`msg.content.toLowerCase().includes("boomer")`

Comment: Ty. I will try that. It is probably the 2nd thing. I'm pretty sure I gave the bot permission to speak. In the channel.

Comment: I think I did something wrong. I have posted the new code in my question and the picture also includes the problems I were getting. If you could please say what the new code should be. I need lots of help because obviously I'm doing something really wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

```js
bot.on('message', message => {
  if (msg.content === "boomer") msg.reply('Im not a boomer!>:(');
});
```

EDIT: The code in your image appears to have a closing bracket in the wrong place

Comment: Ty. I will try that soon.

Comment: now I'm getting an error saying that the node . module cannot be found. It wasn't like this yesterday and I didn't change anything with node.js. How can I fix this?

Comment: Go to directory the file is located in and run `npm install <missing package> --save`

Comment: Ok. Ty for all of the help.